# unable to open X server with ImageMagick Mac osx

Tags: x11, osx, display

I am trying to display an image using the following:

```
Display someimage.jpeg
```

It returns this:

```
display: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/426.
```

I have been looking at other posts and I have tried the following with no luck:

```
export DISPLAY="0.0"
```

Comment: Can you try `DISPLAY=:0 Display someimage.jpeg` ?

Comment: Hi Karlo,
Thanks for the help.
Yes that did work, thanks. Will I need to write DISPLAY=:0 every time I want to display an image? Or is there another way?
Thanks again.

Comment: I converted it into an answer. Let's also figure out why the variable is not being set. What is the output of: `echo "PRE:$DISPLAY"; export DISPLAY=:0; echo "POST:$DISPLAY"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your DISPLAY variable is not being recognized. Run Display via:

```
DISPLAY=:0 Display someimage.jpeg
```

If that works, it is an indication your export is not working correctly. Before running the command, what is the output of `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: the output when I enter echo $DISPLAY is   :0

Comment: That is very weird. If your echo can give it back, then why can't Display see the variable? ...